# Android network job with HeadlessJs in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-service

I have a React-Native problem using HeadlessJs with UDP and TCP requests when the app is killed. I have no problem when using HTTP requests but requests that use `react-native-udp` and `react-native-tcp` are queued.

```
    import dgram from 'react-native-udp'

    class UdpHandler {
      constructor () {
        // always reaching here
        this.socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4')
      }

      send () {
        // sometimes not reaching here
        this.socket.send(...)
      }
    }
```

My headless tasks create an instance of UdpHandler and sometimes send is completed and some other is not reaching there.

I've been trying to use `WifiManager.WifiLock` as this is something that creates network requests while the app is killed or in the background.

I don't know if it depends on the `executor` that `react-native-upd` is using internally.